# Error while executing trigger for auto incrementing a field

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I am trying to execute a trigger for auto incrementing a field.
The script for the table, sequence and trigger gets compiled and executed successfully. However, when I try to insert a record, I get the below error :

```
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'CAR_ON_INSERT' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.
```

Below is the DB script:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR(
    CAR_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CAR_NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
    
);

CREATE SEQUENCE CAR_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CAR_on_insert
  BEFORE INSERT ON CAR
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT CAR_id_seq.nextval
  INTO :new.CAR_ID
  FROM dual;
END;
```

I am not getting whats the issue with this.

Thanks

Comment: Your script works fine for me on Oracle's liveSQL https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/krh4lpt963lfsftm3a0klcaw4 After running the `create trigger` script, do you get errors?  If so, what does `show errors` show?

Comment: A better syntax would be " :new.CAR_ID := CAR_id_seq.nextval; ". There's no need for the query from dual - it only adds unnecessary processing.

Comment: @pmdba - Depending on the Oracle version, of course, which isn't specified.